# Is it possible to insert posts automatically from one WP site to another?

Tags: wordpress

If you need to redesign an existing Wordpress site and are planning to start from the beginning by doing a new template at a different account. Is it possible to insert old posts from the previous site automatically in some way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible if you import post in your database 
OR
You can install "https://wordpress.org/plugins/fakerpress/" this plugin and make it new post as you want